# Is it possible to get and set class variable through different classes?

Tags: java

I tried to instantiate a class with other class A using setter and fetch variable to class B using getter, but it return null. I understand, since I created new instance of class, thats why it is null. What can be other approach?

```
public class ContextBrowser {
String browser;

public String getBrowser() {
    return browser;
}

public void setBrowser(String browser) {
    this.browser = browser;
}
}


public class SetBrowser{

public void setCurrentBrowser(String browser){       
    ContextBrowser contextBrowser =  new ContextBrowser();
    contextBrowser.setBrowser(browser);
}
}


public class getBrowser{

public String readBrowser(){
  ContextBrowser contextBrowser =  new ContextBrowser();
  return contextBrowser.getBrowser()
}
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the existing instance.

Comment: *"I tried to instantiate..."* you didn't show us that. Where's your `main`?

Comment: @SLaks, sure, a sample code will be great help.

Comment: What is the logic of having 3 classes here?

Comment: You need a tutorial on objects, classes, references, and variables.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ContextBrowser {
    /*
    Singleton class
    */

    private String browser;

    private static ContextBrowser contextBrowserInstance;

    // private constructor
    private ContextBrowser() {}

    public static ContextBrowser getContextBrowserInstance() {
        if(contextBrowserInstance == null) {
            contextBrowserInstance = new ContextBrowser();
        }
        return contextBrowserInstance;
    }

    public String getBrowser() {
        return browser;
    }

    public void setBrowser(String browser) {
        this.browser = browser;
    }

}


public class SetBrowser{

    public void setCurrentBrowser(String browser){       
        ContextBrowser contextBrowser =  ContextBrowser.getContextBrowserInstance();
        contextBrowser.setBrowser(browser);
    }
}


public class GetBrowser{

    public String readBrowser(){
      ContextBrowser contextBrowser =  ContextBrowser.getContextBrowserInstance();
      return contextBrowser.getBrowser();
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide some insight on your answer, what it means, what you did, etc. Don't just blatantly give an answer without explaining.

Comment: @moocow sorry to annoy you.. i was just creating a singleton class to set and get instance variable from other classes... i think the code was readable so i didn't explain it...

Answer (score -1):

Improved code with thread safe class:

```
public class ContextBrowser {

private String browser;
private ContextBrowser() {}

public static synchronized ContextBrowser getInstance(){
    return instance.get();
}

public String getBrowser() {
    return browser;
}

public void setBrowser(String browser) {
    this.browser = browser;
}

private static ThreadLocal<ContextBrowser> instance = new ThreadLocal() {

    @Override
    protected ContextBrowser initialValue() {
        return new ContextBrowser();
    }
};
}
```